# Angular 10 --deploy-url assets path in IIS

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular10

After I upgraded to **Angular 10** from version 7, fonts and images of **assets** folders are not getting loaded in browser  and getting 404 Error.

```
http://localhost/assets/fonts/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.woff?v=1.1.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I am hosting my angular app inside a sub-directory in  **IIS** and using `--deploy-url` & `--base-href` switch to build my application.

My build Command:

`ng build --prod --base-href /MyApp/ --deploy-url /MyApp/Scripts/`

Scripts folder contains all the out put of build command.
I am referring images inside my components as :

```
background-image: url(/assets/images/login_bg.png);
```

and referring Fonts as :

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   src: url('/assets/fonts/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.eot?v=1.1.0');
   src: url('/assets/fonts/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('/assets/fonts/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.woff?v=1.1.0') format('woff'), 
   url('/assets/fonts/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.ttf?v=1.1.0') format('truetype'), 
   url('/assets/fonts/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.svg?v=1.1.0#Regular') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

I have notices that build output is different in angular CLI 7 and angular CLI 10.
[image]
Here we can see that with **Angular 7** we have correct path that locates the images in web server but in **Angular 10** we only have partial path that leads to 404 error.

Please suggest.

Comment: Same here. Ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue is logged in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18115)

Basically the recommended solution is to use relative path `../` from component folder to root level `assets` folder.